# Chai expect one out of two properties have a value

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, chai

Is it possible doing in Chai something like?:

```
expect(message).to.have.property('key1', value).or.to.have.property('key2', value);
```

So I mean, property one OR property two have the value.

Comment: `expect([message.key1, message.key2]).to.include(value);` Could work, as long as `value` is not undefined, and `message` exists. Otherwise, I would use a custom matcher using `satisfy`

Answer (score 1):

This could work as long as `value !== undefined` and `message` exists

```
expect([message.key1, message.key2]).to.include(value);
```

Alternatively you could use `satisfy`:

```
expect(message).to.satisfy(msg => {
    if (msg.key1 && msg.key1 === value) return true;
    if (msg.key2 && msg.key2 === value) return true;
    return false;
})
```

[Satisfy](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_satisfy)

Comment: Thanks, the first option is nice